# Заполнить всю высоту родителя с учетом содержимого

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, flexbox

Дан родительский блок(он с фоном с малинкой) он занимает весь вьюпорт(`100vh`)

В нем есть два блока первый имеет высоту `200px`

**А второй нужно растянуть по высоте на всё оставшееся место.**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Вариант 1**

```
.second {
   height: calc(100vh - 200px);
}
```

**Вариант 2**

```
.parrent {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   height: 100vh;
}
.first {
   flex: 0 0 200px;
}
.second {
   flex: 1 0;
}
```

Comment: а если первый тоже неизвестен (в процентах например)

Comment: @VipFilStar неизвестен или в процентах? `calc(100vh - 20%);`

Comment: ну первый блок задан в проц но имеет max-height

Comment: @VipFilStar используйте второй варинат

Comment: ну а там разве 200px не фиксированно

Comment: @VipFilStar в вопросе 200px то же фиксировано, но вы же на ходу изменяете условия. https://codepen.io/aliencash/pen/XRVLvj

Comment: я прост мпросил Большое спасибо вы решили все мои вопросы